# SharePoint 2016 High Trust Application launch issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, provider-hosted-app

I have configured my High Trust Application by following steps mention in below link.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/package-and-publish-high-trust-sharepoint-add-ins

When I launched my app got below error.

***An error occurred while processing your request.***

I did spent some time in digging the issue and after going through below blog I found out the issue and the actual error is ***The Azure Access Control service is unavailable.***

Below details is from request object,

SPRedirectMessage : EndpointAuthorityMatches

SPErrorInfo: The Azure Access Control service is unavailable.

https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/more-troubleshooting-tips-for-high-trust-apps-on-sharepoint-2013/
http://www.chrisjohnson.io/2013/09/20/launching-sharepoint-apps-launch-sequence-debugging-and-appredirect-aspx/

I am using self signed certificate and as per below blog it says that it never works with Self Signed certificate. But as per microsoft's site it should work

http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/2012/09/25/the-azure-access-control-service-is-unavailable/

Really appreciate if anyone can help me setting up High Trust AddIn on my SharePoint 2016 environment.

Comment: The ACS error is usually erroneous and is a fallback message. Typically the error resolves around the high trust cert, e.g. the app doesn't have access to it or SharePoint doesn't properly trust it, etc.

Comment: Thanks @TrevorSeward . Is there a way to nail down the isssue. For e.g. getting details from ULS. While I was looking at ULS got "Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=" message. Does this looks good to you?

Comment: Not without seeing the app package and web.config associated with the app as well as the generated ID in the App Catalog. That message isn't an error message, just a generic message indicating the request isn't an OAuth one.

Comment: I have configured my SharePoint web app with SSL certificate. Will that be an issue?

Comment: I just reset everything all over again and when I press F5 it works. But when I packaged it to IIS got error which says "Cannot construct a X509SigningCredentials instance for a certificate without the private key."

Comment: Finally, I was able to fix the issue. The issue was with the serial number. It had some special characters which I couldn't see but when I checked the length it was more then I could see. The answer to this question helped me fix my issue.  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150573/having-problem-using-iis-8-self-signed-certificate-for-sharepoint-2013-high-trus